# SQL Script to scan through a data table1, find the specific field, then copy it into table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me fix this script?

> I get this error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part
>   identifier "#Temp3.EmpID" could not be bound.

the error is coming from: -- Update into Keyshop.EmployeeTable
UPDATE EmployeeTable SET Status = 'False' WHERE #Temp3.EmpID = EmployeeTable.EmpID

The script is pretty self explanatory but let me know if you need me to provide more info.
Thank you

```
-- Update into Keyshop.EmployeeTable
UPDATE EmployeeTable SET Status = 'False' WHERE #Temp3.EmpID = EmployeeTable.EmpID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a valid update statement since it references a table not in the `UPDATE` Clause or the Optional `FROM` clause

```
UPDATE EmployeeTable
 SET Status = 'False' 
WHERE #Temp3.EmpID = EmployeeTable.EmpID
```

There are several ways to do it using `IN` is probably the easiest to understand

```
UPDATE EmployeeTable
 SET Status = 'False' 
WHERE EmployeeTable.EmpID IN (SELECT EmpID  FROM #Temp3)
```

Comment: yea i had a feeling the equal sign felt funny, iam still in process of learning sql better. I was going to try using Alias, but your fix is so much better. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch these guys around. Instead of this:

```
UPDATE EmployeeTable SET Status = 'False' WHERE #Temp3.EmpID = EmployeeTable.EmpID
```

Have this

```
UPDATE EmployeeTable SET Status = 'False' WHERE EmployeeTable.EmpID in (SELECT EmpID  FROM #Temp3)
```

Edit: I missed that #Temp3.EmpID is a table, not a variable.